# 英語が残っている：コミュニティWikiのチェックボックスをクリックしたときのダイアログ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語, 英語

コミュニティWikiのチェックボックスをクリックしたときの確認ダイアログが英文のままのようです。

[image: community wiki]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Transifexに登録されていた](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/50799521?comment=%2Fq%2F1913%2F)ので、すぐにでも修正可能です。

以下の翻訳でいかがでしょうか？（スニペットにしてみましたが、ブラウザによっては動作しません）

```js
confirm(
  "この投稿をコミュニティWikiに変換しますか？" +
  "\n\n" +
  "これによりあなたは投稿の所有者ではなくなり、投票による信用度も獲得できなくなります。" +
  "一度コミュニティWikiに変換された投稿を元の形式に戻すには、モデレーターの助力が必要です。"
)
```

Comment: 変換するという言葉を補った方がわかりやすいのではないかと思います。翻訳案：「この投稿をコミュニティWikiに変換しますか？」「いったんコミュニティWikiに変換された投稿を元の形式に戻すには、モデレーターの助力が必要です」

Comment: @holywise 「変換する」、ひと手間かかりそうな感じがいいですね。

Comment: とりあえずこの文章でTransifexに反映しました。反映までお待ちください。